# Why can't I use this variable in my for loop?

Tags: javascript, forms, loops, input

So I am having an issue with running the loop for this function. It does not appear I can use *var formappend* in the for loop, even though my *var formappend* returns a number to the console when I input a number into the form.

```
var formappend = $('input[name=inputform]').val();
  for (var i = 0; i < formappend; i++){
      $('button').one('click', function(i) {
            var newblock = $("<div class='block'></div>").text("");
            $('#funbox').append(newblock);
                });
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: because that would be a `string`, not a `Number`

Comment: Try parsing `formappend` as an int first, using `parseInt()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: try this: `parseInt($('input[name=inputform]').val());`

Comment: What's `$('button').one`?

Comment: Thanks guys parseInt(); makes sense. Reason I used ('button').one is because I want to limit the click event to only a single click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to run 'for' loop inside the click handler. Currently you bind a click handler inside a 'for' loop, so try this:

```
$('button').on('click', function(i) {
    $('#funbox').text('');
    var formappend = parseInt($('input[name=inputform]').val());
    if(isNaN(formappend)) return false;

    for (var i = 0; i < formappend; i++){      
        var newblock = $("<div class='block'></div>").text("");
        $('#funbox').append(newblock);
    }
});
```

Check this out:
https://jsfiddle.net/s24edozb/5/

Comment: @Jordan, did you apply a changed script. Is it working for you?

Comment: Gotcha, it all makes sense when I read the code but I'm still having issues.

Comment: What's confusing me is that when I give the for a loop a number, it does what I want it to. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/JordanS1234/s24edozb/4/         The issue now is why my form input isn't working even when I have used parseInt.

Comment: As well @Marek, putting the for loop inside the click handler proves to be an issue. Intuitively it makes sense, perhaps my syntax is incorrect.

Comment: One more change needed is to move `var formappend = parseInt($('input[name=inputform]').val());` as a first line in 'click' handler. What it changes? It will evaluate the input value at the moment of clicking, not at the moment of page loading. I just change the answer code, so please doublecheck it.

Comment: Rad! Thanks Marek!

Answer (score 0):

formappend is not an integer, it's a string after it's returned from this call:

```
$('input[name=inputform]').val();
```

Try calling parseInt() on the result like this:

```
var formappend = parseInt($('input[name=inputform]').val());
```

Also, I think you meant to call the `.on` method, not the `.one` method on your button